# How do I build my Linux c++ app to link to an old version of libc?

Tags: c++, linux, linker, g++, embedded-linux

I have built an app on Ubuntu 12.04 and have tried running it on an embedded system. I ran `apt-cache show libc6` on my dev machine which shows (amongst other things)

```
Package: libc6
Priority: required
Section: libs
Architecture: i386
Source: eglibc
Version: 2.15-0ubuntu10
Replaces: belocs-locales-bin, libc6-i386
Provides: glibc-2.13-1, libc6-i686
```

The version of libc6 that exists on the embedded device is 2.8.90. In the `\lib` directory on the device I have 2 libs

```
libc-2.8.90.so
libc.so.6
```

When I copy my application onto the embedded device I get the following errors

```
/usr/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15` not found (required by ./ServerSocketApp)
```

I know that if possible I when I build the application on my dev maching I need to force it to link to the same version of libc6 as exists on the embedded device. The problem I have is that I simply do not know how to do this. Any answers that I have found are meaningless to me right now. Is there some option that I need to pass to g++ to get this to link to version 2.8.90 ??

In desperation I am thinking is it possible to copy the libc on my dev machine onto the embedded device in place of what is there already and hope for the best??? I just cannot seem to find any documentation online that explains in simple terms how you even go about this so any advice at all would be really really welcome as I am tearing my hair out here.

Comment: have you tried passing it directly the full path of the .so file (instead of -lc) ?

Comment: Not yet, I will certainly give this a try - thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried static linking? You can also setup a chrooted environment with the older glibc version and use it to compile for the embedded system.

Comment: @HristoIliev I have thought about static linking and it may well have to be the way forward. I would really just like to know how to do this issue seems to be cropping up a lot. I am really new to embedded stuff so I am absorbing a lot of info at the moment but not getting much progress. I will certainly do some research on your suggestion. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fundamentally incorrect. While you may be able to hack together a way to link in the old libc, the problem is your environment setup.

When you develop applications for an embedded system. You do so on a host. Generally, the host and embedded device are not on the same architecture. For example, your host is usually a desktop/laptop running on an x86 and the embedded system might be on an ARM. If you happen to be on the same architecture as your embedded device, that is sheer coincidence. Standard practice environment setup should still follow:

- The host machine should have a tool chain setup to cross build applications to the embedded architecture
- The host machine should have a copy of the full rootfs that exists your embedded device. This will contain all of the libraries that your cross tools will use to compile applications for the embedded system

If you have it setup this way. Development will be easy. You will be able to setup simple, clean make files to build your applications and then just `scp` the binaries over to the embedded system and run.

Comment: Can you suggest the tools with which to do this - or an online resource that does so???

Comment: I don't know the details of your embedded system. But generally companies will provide a base to work from. For example, Freescale provides ltib which allows you to build or extract functional u-boot, rootfs, kernel, etc for the reference board you bought. If you are just looking for a tool chain and one isn't provided, you can build it yourself: http://kegel.com/crosstool/. Though it sounded like the architecture of your embedded device was the same as your host. So you don't need to cross compile. you just need a clean development environment to work with and the rootfs of your device.

Comment: Yes the architecture is the same. So I basically just need to find a way to extract the file system from my board into my machine, build the necessary libraries and binary on host machine then copy back to the device?

Comment: Yes, if a minimal rootfs isn't provided for you. The alternative is you can tar up everything from the base directory of the embedded device and scp that to your host. I recommend working out a clean project tree so you can setup paths sanely. 
Example
/project/embedded_device/applications/...
/project/embedded_device/bootloader/...
/project/embedded_device/rootfs/...
/project/embedded_device/kernel/...

Answer (score 9):

OK, here is a somewhat longer explanation, but proceed with care. I still strongly recommend that you setup a chrooted environment to match the one available on the embedded device and use it during the last stage of your build process.

You should understand how dynamically linked ELF executables are loaded and executed. There is something called *the run-time link editor* (RTLD), also known as the dynamic linker, that takes care of loading all the necessary dynamically linked libraries, fixing relocations and so on. The name of the dynamic linker is `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` on 32-bit Linux systems with `glibc2` and `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` on 64-bit Linux systems with 
`glibc2`. The dynamic linker is **very** tightly coupled to the `glibc2` library and usually can only handle the matching version of that library. Also the path to it is *hardcoded* into the executable by the linker (usually `ld`, implicitly called by the compiler to do the linking). You can easily check the validty of the last statement by simply doing `ldd some_elf_executable` - the run-time link editor shows up with the full path:

```
$ ldd some_elf_executable
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffab59e000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003648400000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003648800000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003648000000) <--- the RTLD
```

In order to produce a dynamically linked executable that uses a version of `glibc2` different from the one installed on the system, where the executable is to be run, you should link your code with the following set of options to `ld`:

- `-rpath=/path/to/newer/libs` - this one instructs the dynamic linker to first search `/path/to/newer/libs` when trying to resolve library dependencies. `/path/to/newer/libs` should match the path where you have copied the newer `glibc2` version on the embedded device
- `-rpath-link=/path/to/newer/libs` - this option instructs the linker (not the dynamic linker) to use `/path/to/newer/libs` when resolving dependencies between shared libraries during link time - this should not be normally necessary in your case
- `--dynamic-linker=/path/to/newer/libs/ld-linux.so.2` - this one overrides the path to the RTLD that gets embedded into the executable

The way to provide those options to `ld` is usually via the `-Wl` option of GCC.

```
-rpath=/path/to/newer/libs
```

becomes:

```
-Wl,-rpath,/path/to/newer/libs
```

(notice that the `=` is replaced by `,`)

```
--dynamic-linker=/path/to/newer/libs/ld-linux.so.2
```

becomes:

```
-Wl,--dynamic-linker,/path/to/newer/libs/ld-linux.so.2
```

You should copy `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` from your development system to `/path/to/newer/libs/` on the embedded device. You should also copy `libc.so.6`, the mathematical library `libm.so.6` and all the other libraries that are used by the executable or that might get loaded indirectly. Note that `libc.so.6` and `libm.so.6` are actually symbolic links to the real libraries which have names like `libc-2.<version>.so`. You should copy those library files and create the appropriate symbolic links to make everybody happy.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer I will try this first thing tomorrow. It also gives me some extra keywords to go off and research. Coming from windows it is a real shock to me just how difficult it is to get to grips developing something on linux that will run on a machine configured differently. I cannot believe that there are not more tutorials about this kind of thing online. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You might have some luck compiling with the LSB SDK (http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/lsb/download) which restricts the symbols available to the executable.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion I will certainly explore this option.